# Getting 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch when uploading to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: javascript, python, file-upload, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload audio files on the Client-Side directly to my Google Cloud Storage bucket, for the purpose of avoiding a server-side upload (which has file size limits).

My Issue: I am getting a 403  SignatureDoesNotMatch  error on upload.

Here is the error from the response:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method</Message>
<StringToSign>
PUT

audio/mp3
1511112552
/bucketname/pathtofile/019%20-%20top%20cntndr%20V1.mp3
</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I have created a signed url. It looks like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/google-testbucket/testdata.txt?GoogleAccessId=
1234567890123@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1331155464&Signature=BCl
z9e4UA2MRRDX62TPd8sNpUCxVsqUDG3YGPWvPcwN%2BmWBPqwgUYcOSszCPlgWREeF7oPGowkeKk
7J4WApzkzxERdOQmAdrvshKSzUHg8Jqp1lw9tbiJfE2ExdOOIoJVmGLoDeAGnfzCd4fTsWcLbal9
sFpqXsQI8IQi1493mw%3D
```

The signed url is built following the guidlines found in the Google Docs here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program

However, the client-side javascript portion of handling this signed url is very unclear in the documentation.

**Here is my python code to create and return the signed url.**

```
GOOGLE_SERVICE_CREDENTIALS = 'google-service-credentials.json'

def get_signed_url(request):
    filename = request.GET.get('filename')
    expiration = request.GET.get('expiration')
    type = request.GET.get('type')
    signed_url = CloudStorageSignedURL(
                method='PUT',
                file_name=filename,
                expiration_m=expiration,
                content_type=type
                )
    signed_url = signed_url.sign_url()


    return JsonResponse({ 'signed_url': signed_url })






class CloudStorageSignedURL(object):


    def __init__(self, method, file_name, expiration_m, content_type):
        self.HTTP_method = method
        self.content_type = 'content-type: ' + content_type
        self.expiration = int(expiration_m)
        self.file_name = file_name


    def sign_url(self):


        expiration_dt = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=self.expiration)
        expiration = int(time.mktime( expiration_dt.timetuple() ))
        bucket_path = '/' + settings.CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET + '/dev/tests/' + self.file_name
        signature_string = self.HTTP_method + '\n' + '\n' + self.content_type + "\n" + str(expiration) + '\n' + bucket_path
        print(signature_string)
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(GOOGLE_SERVICE_CREDENTIALS)
        client_email = creds.service_account_email
        signature = creds.sign_blob(signature_string)[1]
        encoded_signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature).decode('utf-8')
        base_url = settings.CLOUD_STORAGE_ROOT + 'dev/tests/' + self.file_name


        return base_url + '?GoogleAccessId=' + client_email + '&Expires=' + str(expiration) + '&Signature=' + encoded_signature
```

**Client-side Javascript to upload the file**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from 'axios';



$("document").ready( () => {
  console.log('window loaded');


  $("#id_audio_file").change(function() {

    const file = this.files[0]

    const url = window.location.href.replace('submit/', 'upload/');
    $.get(url + `?filename=${file.name}&expiration=10&type=${file.type}`, (data) => {
      upload(data.signed_url, file);
    })

  });
});



function upload(url, file) {

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': file.type,
    }
  }

  axios.put(url, file, config)
    .then(function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I really feel like I covered all the bases here, but I am obviously missing something minute.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Expires=1331155464` means that access provided by the URL expired some 5 years ago. Still, the error would have been:


`<Error> 
<Code>ExpiredToken</Code> 
<Message>The provided token has expired.</Message> 
<Details>Request has expired: timestamp</Details> 
</Error> `. I suggest using [the API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/signblob/m/iam/v1/iam.projects.serviceAccounts.signBlob) to generate a signature as an alternative to `sign_url`, for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that the service account that you are using has the proper permissions to upload a file to a bucket: either through [IAM settings](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) or through [access control](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists).

If this is set, then it's a matter of the code. I have tried your approach, with creating the signed url *rather manually* and it failed for me as well, with the same error. But, I have managed to upload a file via a signedURL, using the `generate_signed_url` method from [the Google Cloud python client library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html). Less talk, more code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import base64
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import requests
from google.cloud import storage

# client = storage.Client()
# bucket = client.get_bucket('a-test-bucket')
# blob = bucket.blob('/test/mpthreetest.mp3')

GOOGLE_SERVICE_CREDENTIALS = 'signed_url_account.json'
FILENAME = 'mpthreetest.mp3'
EXPIRATION = 1511826970  # epoch time
TYPE = 'audio/mp3'

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(GOOGLE_SERVICE_CREDENTIALS)
bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket('a-test-bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('test/mpthreetest.mp3')

signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(method='PUT', expiration=EXPIRATION, content_type=TYPE, credentials=creds)

print (signed_url)

req = requests.put(signed_url, open(FILENAME), headers={'Content-Type': TYPE})
print(req.content)
```

Comment: Does this approach work for putting files in a bucket? I am trying to generate a signed url for the bucket (PUT) and send that to the browser so that the browser can upload directly to the bicket without having to go through the server. Pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.